# How to identify which version spring framework to use when upgrading java 1.7 webapp to openjdk 19?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, hibernate3, tomcat10

Few years back, I develop a web application using Java 1.7, SpringFramework 4.1.1.RELEASE and Hibernate 3.6.10.Final. This webapp is running on Tomcat 7.0.4 at the time.

Now, I planning to upgrade and compile everything using OpenJDK 19, and Tomcat 10.1.
How do I know which version to use in my pom.xml (Maven) so that theres no error after compilation and during runtime.

WHat should I do first?

Using the latest Eclipse and I have downloaded both Tomcat 10.1 and OpenJDK 19.
I've set the Java Compiler to openJDK 19 and added both JRE System Library and Server Runtime in the build path.
I have also added some more jar file to fix issues in Marker tab but I encountered error during starting up application.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat 10.1 uses [Servlet API 6.0](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/servletapi/index.html) which is now part of Jakarta EE. As part of the move from Java EE to Jakarta EE, the packages in `javax.servlet.*` are moved to `jakarta.servlet.*` since the error you are getting.

If your target platform is Tomcat 10.1, you should move to Spring Framework 6.

Check the [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-6.x#web-applications)

Comment: How about the Hibernate version? Do I have to upgrade the version which compatible with Spring 6.0?

Comment: Yes. You must upgrade Hibernate to 6.1 https://spring.io/blog/2022/11/16/spring-framework-6-0-goes-ga